# Layered Navigation: Always show full category tree

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, layered-navigation

Consider the following category tree:

```
A
  A1
    A11
  A2
    A21
    A22
B
  B1
C
```

By default, the categories listed in the layered navigation are the child categories of the current category, so for example if I opened up the `A/A2` category in the front end, the following categories would be shown in the layered navigation:

```
A21
A22
```

Is there a way to always show the full category tree, starting from the root category? A lot of shops seem to do this but I haven't found a way yet to do this with Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code on top of **template/catalog/layer/view.phtml**

```
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat_path    = $obj->getCurrentCategoryPath();
$current_cat_name   = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getId() == $current_cat_path[0] || $cat->getId() == $current_cat_path[1]) {
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="../'.$cat->getData('request_path').'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($cat->getChildren() as $subcat) {
            if ($subcat->getId() == $current_cat_path[0]){
                echo '<li class="here"><a href="../'.$subcat->getData('request_path').'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
            }else{
                echo '<li><a href="../'.$subcat->getData('request_path').'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="../'.$cat->getData('request_path').'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This in Block file or helper file (i prefer helper)

```
    public function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild)
{
    $allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId))
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');

    $class = ($isChild) ? "sub-cat-list" : "cat-list";
    $html .= '<ul class="'.$class.'">';

    foreach($allCats as $category) {

        $subcats = $category->getChildren();
        $subhtml = '';
        if(!empty($subcats)){
            $subhtml = $this->getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);
        }


        $html .= '<li><div class="product_categories_list">';
                      if( (!empty($subhtml))){
                          $html .= '<span class="accor"></span>';
                      }else{
                          $html .= '<span class="no-accor"></span>';
                      }

                      if (count($_testproductCollection) <= 0)
                      {
                          $html.='<span class="product_block_count_zero">';
                          $html.= $category->getName();
                          $html.='</span>';
                      }
                      else{
                      $html .= '<a data-url="'.$category->getUrl().'"
                           name="'.cat.'" class="ajaxfilter"  value="'.$category->getId().'"
                            href="'.$category->getUrl().'">'.$category->getName().'</a>';
                      }

                    if(!empty($subhtml)){
                        $html .= $subhtml;
                    }

        $html .= '</div></li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Now in the phtml file u can send call like this

```
$catlistHtml = $helper->getTreeCategories($ParentCatagoryID, false);
```